# Buddypress avatar roots theme

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I'm sort of new to WP and BP, is there a way to render a BP avatar in my WP roots theme?
I want the avatar to show in a menu bar when the use is logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, BP has a function you can use to output an avatar:

```
$args = array( 'item_id' => $user_id, 'type' => 'full' );
echo bp_core_fetch_avatar( $args );
```

$user_id should be changed to the ID of the user you want. i.e. `bp_displayed_user_id()` or `bp_loggedin_user_id()`